# How to resolve 'No internet connectivity issues' with a Virtualised 2008 R2 Server using Forefront UAG

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I have spent some considerable time reading up on as many possible blogs and articles as I can to help me solve why my VM (Running on Hyper-V) for DirectAccess has suddenly stopped being able to access the internet. The VM setup shares the same internet connection on which I have written and submitted this question so I know that the actual underlying internet connection is fully functional.

Previous to last week the DirectAccess was fully functional and had no issues. This is a recent problem which was led up to by a number of consistent crashes on the DA machine when access was attempted. Upon reboot all seemed well until recently.

I am not certain whether it is relevant, but previously to this I had a number of power issues where the entire VM host shutdown unexpectedly leaving around 8 VM's in a bad way. Upon restart, the UAG DirectAccess machine was unable to access its configuration service (although the service was started) but this seemed to relate to the Light-Weight Active Directory Service AD LDS which had a corrupted database. Having repaired this database, I restarted the service and could subsequently reconnect to the configuration service again.

For good measure I re-bound the network adapters (virtualised through Hyper-V) and DirectAccess claimed to be all happy again. However as it stands my machine is still unable to access the internet showing the "No internet connectivity" exclamation mark for the external facing NIC. I have also tried removing the adapters, disabling, re-enabling and the problem persists.

The intranet part of the VM CorpNet seems to be fully functional as before and I'm running out of ideas. Any input would be greatly appreciated. I am not an advanced Domain Administrator so please be gentle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall the Physical NIC and install them again on the HV machine, and than recreate the Virtual Network again using the Physical NIC, try to doing restart specially to the AD